# Use UITableView cell as UIView and change it colour permanently by tapping it (Colour source comes from function generating random colour)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I wanted to assign action to UITableView cell for when it is tapped to change its colour permanently using a function that generates random UIColor.

I am a complete beginner and could not find anything that could help me or i would understand. I count not for 100% solution (That'd be welcome) but if i'll get any help that could let me get on track with this i'd really appreciate.

Below is my code for the given controller (written with help of a tutorial):

```
import UIKit

class FruitsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{
        //Generate between 0 to 1
        let red:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }


    // MARK: - Table View data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write below `UITableView` Delegate in your class:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) {

     let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
     let color = getRandomColor()
     cell.backgroundColor = color
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color

    }
```

It might again change color while scrolling as you are reusing your cells.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

Use a variable to check the selection of TableViewCell. [image]

```
var isSelected : Bool! = false


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LocationCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)

    if isSelected == true
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = self.getRandomColor()
    }
    else
    {

    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    isSelected = true
    tblView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
}
```

Comment: As you took isSelected global variable so after single tap and scroll it will change the color of all cells.

Comment: No, it updates color of only selected cell. Because I am reloading a particular row, not tableview.

Comment: what if when tableview scroll? after single tap.